# can I use serviceAutoStartProviders for azure web app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My site's first query is quite slow (as I am using code first and by design the first query will be much more than just query the database).

I read that I can create a prewarmer and config applicationHost.config like this:

```
in <application> tag: 
set serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" serviceAutoStartProvider="PrewarmMyApp"
Add the following XML after </site>:

<serviceAutoStartProviders>
    <add 
        name="PrewarmMyApp" 
        type="MyWebApp.PreWarmUp, MyWebApp" />
</serviceAutoStartProviders>
```

But in azure, can I modify applicationHost.config to insert these? If not, is there anything else I can do?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we could [access Applicationhost.config file in Azure Web Sites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/harikharan/2015/02/11/how-to-accessdownload-applicationhost-config-file-in-azure-web-sites/) under “Config” folder via KUDU console tool.

[image]

but ApplicationHost.config configuration file is not available for direct editing in App Service, the platform supports a declarative ApplicationHost.config transform model based on [XML Document Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-transform-extend) (XDT), we could enable custom web app administration actions by using XDT.

Besides, if your app requires [custom warm-up actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing#custom-warm-up-before-swap), you could try to specify custom initialization actions and deploy the app to a staging slot, and then swap into production slot.

Comment: hi, can I transform serviceAutoStartProviders section and application section? I thought it was quite limited on what I can. About deployment slot, my app has scale out setting set 2-4 instances, will all instances get warmed up?

Comment: Using application initialization module with Azure Web App deployment slots could ensure that the application in the slot is completely warmed up during the swap operation, which should meet your requirement. For more detailed information, please refer to [how to warm up Azure Web App during deployment slots swap](http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/). And in my opinion, all instances should be warmed up.